# i am getting error when i am fetching user data from database in laravel through API

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, fetch-api

Hello Guys nowadays am working on laravel api everything is perfect just one issue am facing that is when i write wrong username and password so i am able to get user data but when i enter correct user information so i am getting exception that is invalid credentials. please help me

here is my model code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class email extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

&
Here is my Controller Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\email;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
   public function databyemail(Request $request){   
       $data = email::where('email', $request->email)->first();  
       if($data->password === bcrypt($request->password)) 
       {
           return response()->json($data);
       } 
       else
       {      
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect credentials!']);  
           } 
           }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `Hash::check` method for matching password.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;
use App\email;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
   public function databyemail(Request $request){   
        $data = email::where('email', $request->email)->first(); 


        if( Hash::check( $request->password, $data->password ) ) {
            return response()->json($data);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect credentials!']);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadSajidLakha I think you had another issue. What is your laravel version?
First, try `dd($data)` before match password. And check get user data or not?

Comment: @MuhammadSajidLakha You should add `Use Hash;` before the controller class.

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\email;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
   public function databyemail(Request $request){   
       $data = email::where('email', $request->email)->first();  
       if($data->password === bcrypt($request->password))
       {
           return response()->json($data);
       } 
       else
       {      
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect credentials!']);  
           } 
           }
    
}

Comment: my laravel version is 5.7

Comment: @MuhammadSajidLakha I have updated my answer. if any error happen add full error status.